# Adjust equation to accomodate x values < 1 in log10(x)

Tags: logarithms

I have taken an equation from an article which was fitted on x being 1 (kg) at a minimum, the equation is as follows

log10(y) = -0.619 + 0.812 * log10(x)^1.171

But now I would like to use the equation to calculate values of x when x<1, but if x<1 than log10(x) is <0 so this doesn't work. I don't have the original data so I can't refit the function. How can I modify the equation so values of x can be < 1?

[image: original graph from article]

Comment: It is not meaningful for $x<1$.  Near $x=1$ you have $y \approx 0.2404363$.  If you plot $y$ against $x$ for $x \ge 1$, it looks close to linear, though it seems to me $\frac{dy}{dx} \to 0$ as $x \to 1^{+}$, so really anything could happen for smaller $x$ if you try to extrapolate down.  I would be interested in what motivated this model in the original article, rather than something more natural: $1$kg looks like an artificial  minimum mass.

Comment: @Henry I guess they didn't have enough data in that region to fit a model. I have posted the original graph.

Comment: Now you have included the graph, there is even less reason to justify extrapolating below $10^0$ with that complicated function. For the ruminants the log-log graph is close to linear with a slope close to $1$ so perhaps you might sensibly use something like  $y \approx 0.19 x$.  For the hindgut animals, the difference between Porcupine and Rock Hydrax is so far off the blue line that extrapolating downwards is unlikely to be helpful in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no answer to your question. There are an infinite number of possible ways to change the function to work for a larger domain (where x < 1), especially without the original data.

It's the same type of question of "what number follows after 1 2 4 7" - there are infinitely many patterns/equations that would satisfy this start.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Is there anyway that I could do a linear extrapolation so that the blue curve in the graph can be plotted for x < 1?